# Plurals of two concepts expressed by two word whose second word is the same (i.e. Thermal and Ductile damage)

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, verbs, phrase-choice, plural-forms

This is my first query.
I have a doubt for the following sentence:

*Thermal and ductile damage depend*

Microsoft office is always highlighting it as a mistake as it consider it a singular. This is a really basic attempt to be succinct. The full sentence would be:
*Thermal damage and ductile damage depend on*
What I should write to be correct?
Thanks in advance for the replies.
Cheers

Comment: Plural 'depend' is OK. MS Word/Office grammar checker is very bad. Turn it off.

Comment: Grammar checkers do their best, but none are perfect. If you search this site for "Grammarly" or "grammar check", you'll see that almost every answer is that the grammar checker was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

This is also my (kinda) first answer, so please check other answers and feel free to add more. I think there are a couple of things to consider here.

1. According to the subject-verb agreement, the verb should be singular if the subject noun is singular.
2. Uncountable nouns are singular by default, even when they are associated with multiple adjectives.
3. According to the [dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/damage_1#:%7E:text=damage-,noun,damage%20brain%2Fliver%2C%20etc.), the word **damage** is uncountable if it means physical harm or harmful effects.

So my conclusion is MS Word is right for this one.